# nhibernate - criteria through intermediate table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-criteria

I have a table Team and I have a table Location. Each team can have multiple locations and each location could have multiple teams, so it is a many to many relationship.

When this scenario is created in the database, there will be 3 tables, Team, Location and TeamLocation to hold the many to many links.

I have mapped this in nhibernate using the following...
Team.hbm.xml

```
<class name="App.Data.Entities.Team,App.Data.Entities" table="`Team`" lazy="true">
   <id name="Teamid" column="`TeamID`" type="Guid">
      <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property type="string" not-null="true" length="250" name="TeamName" column="`TeamName`" />
    <bag name="TeamLocations" inverse="false" table="`TeamLocations`" lazy="true" cascade="all">
      <key column="`TeamID`" />
      <many-to-many class="App.Data.Entities.Location,App.Data.Entities">
        <column name="`LocationID`" />
      </many-to-many>
    </bag>
    </class>
```

and Location.hbm.xml

```
<class name="App.Data.Entities.Location,App.Data.Entities" table="`Location`" lazy="true">
    <id name="Locationid" column="`LocationID`" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property type="string" not-null="true" length="250" name="LocationName" column="`LocationName`" />
    <property type="string" length="1000" name="Address" column="`Address`" />
    <bag name="Teams" inverse="false" table="`TeamLocations`" lazy="true" cascade="all">
      <key column="`LocationID`" />
      <many-to-many class="App.Data.Entities.Team,App.Data.Entities">
        <column name="`TeamID`" />
      </many-to-many>
    </bag>
  </class>
```

Now I am trying to retrieve all teams which are based in a specific location using criteria API, which I am unable to..

Equivalent sql...

```
SELECT     Team.TeamName, Location.LocationName
FROM         Team INNER JOIN
                      TeamLocations ON Team.TeamID = TeamLocations.TeamID INNER JOIN
                      Location ON TeamLocations.LocationID = Location.LocationID
WHERE     (TeamLocations.LocationID = 2)
```

and in asp.net code

```
ICriteria criteria = _session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Team)).SetFirstResult(startRowIndex).SetMaxResults(maximumRows);

if (deptID > 0)
{
    Department dept = new Department(deptID);
    criteria.Add(Expression.Eq(Team.PropertyNames.Department, dept)); //for department, which works fine.
}

if (locationIDs.Count > 0)
{
    List<Location> locations = new List<Location>();

    foreach (int locationID in locationIDs)
    {
        Location loc = new Location(locationID);
        locations.Add(loc);
    }

    criteria.CreateCriteria("TeamLocations").Add(Expression.Eq(""TeamLocations"", locations));
}

return criteria.List<Team>();
```

This throws and error..

```
could not resolve property: TeamLocations of: App.Data.Entities.Location
```

which I cant seen to figure out :(

Correct me..
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [restriction to an association path using CreateCriteria or CreateAlias](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-13-criteria-queries#13%282E%294%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Associations) as I did below. I would have to know more about your model and mapping to understand why you can add a restriction on Team.PropertyNames.Department without aliasing it.

```
    ICriteria criteria = _session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Team)).SetFirstResult(startRowIndex).SetMaxResults(maximumRows);

if (deptID > 0)
{
    Department dept = new Department(deptID);
    criteria.Add(Expression.Eq(Team.PropertyNames.Department, dept)); //for department, which works fine.
}

if (locationIDs.Count > 0)
{
    // you may need to convert locationIds to an ICollection e.g.
    // var ids = locationIds.ToArray();
    criteria.CreateAlias("TeamLocations", "teamLocations");
    criteria.Add(Restrictions.In("teamLocations.LocationId", locationIds));
}

return criteria.List<Team>();
```